# unable to boot beagleboard - xM with Demo Angstrom image

Tags: boot, beagleboard

I am facing some issues while trying to install Angstrom on a new 8 GB SD card for a Beagleboard-xM, rev C. My beagleboard does not boot.

I used the following link to download the images and followed the procedure given on the same page below:

[Beagleboard demo files](http://downloads.angstrom-distribution.org/demo/beagleboard)

I am using the **Angstrom-Beagleboard-demo-image-glibc-ipk-2011.1-beagleboard.rootfs.tar.bz2** image.

I am getting the following output via the serial port.

```
U-Boot SPL 2011.12-00010-ga3eb89c (Jan 29 2012 - 14:53:43)
Texas Instruments Revision detection unimplemented
OMAP SD/MMC: 0
reading u-boot.img

U-Boot 2011.12-00010-ga3eb89c (Jan 29 2012 - 14:53:43)

OMAP36XX/37XX-GP ES1.2, CPU-OPP2, L3-165MHz, Max CPU Clock 1 Ghz
OMAP3 Beagle board + LPDDR/NAND
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0
*** Warning - readenv() failed, using default environmen

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Beagle xM Rev C
No EEPROM on expansion board
Die ID #42bc00029ff80000016849a90402a009
Net:   Net Initialization Skipped
No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
The user button is currently NOT pressed.
SD/MMC found on device 0
reading uEnv.txt

** Unable to read "uEnv.txt" from mmc 0:1 **
Loading file "/boot/uImage" from mmc device 0:2 (xxa2)
3195484 bytes read
Booting from mmc ...
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 80200000 ...
Image Name:   Angstrom/2.6.32/beagleboard
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    3195420 Bytes = 3 MiB
Load Address: 80008000
Entry Point:  80008000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux.......................................done, booting the kernel.
```

But nothing happens after the **booting the kernel**. The output freezes.

There are number of doubts I am having:

1. Is this the right image for beagleboard xM (or is it meant only for beagleboard (old hardware) )?
2. Is it that the board boots but I am not able to see the output on the console through the serial port? I am using screen for talking to serial port

   ```
   screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
   ```
3. I see an error related to a uEnv.txt in the log. Is this error causing the symptom?
4. Am I missing a step somewhere? I used the guidelines on the same link above to create a new partitions and flash new image on the SD card.

Comment: Have you verified its the right image?  Have you verified this configuration is able to display the output through serial?  Both of these question can be found on the `Angstrom` website

Comment: yes, the log posted above is from the serial port itself. I am though not sure if after boot, it supports serial port. I could not find any relevant documentation anywhere. In the log posted above, it says..**In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial**. which probably means it does support.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your power supply. Try to power up the board using barrel jack instead of usb.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because the Angstrom image you are using is corrupted

> Angstrom-Beagleboard-demo-image-glibc-ipk-2011.1-beagleboard.rootfs.tar.bz2

To solve that issue I recommend you to use this version instead

> Angstrom-Cloud9-IDE-eglibc-ipk-v2011.11-core-beagleboard.rootfs.tar.bz2